# Converting from lower case to upper case

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I am trying to convert from lower case to upper case. I know it can easily be done by,

```
SUB AL, 20H
```

But I am have been given another solution which is,

```
AND AL, 0DFH
```

Please help me understand this. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the bit patterns:

- A (0x41): `0100 0001`
- a (0x61): `0110 0001`
- M (0x4d): `0100 1101`
- m (0x6d): `0110 1101`
- Z (0x5a): `0101 1010`
- z (0x7a): `0111 1010`

Lower case ASCII is upper case ASCII + 0x20 (`0010 0000`) - i.e. the same bit pattern with *the sixth bit set*.

0xdf is `1101 1111` in binary. AND:ing AL with that will set the sixth bit to zero but preserve the other bit values.

Answer (score 2):

`SUB AL, 20H`is subtracting 0x20 from AL

`AND AL,0DFH`will clear bit 5 (make it '0') . 
Because 0x20 is 00100000 ,subtracting it from a value its the same as just clear bit 5.